# How to suppress Authorization Request notifications?

Tags: bluetooth, notification, blueman

I have connected with a Bluetooth speaker through blueman(-applet). All works fine, however I get a perpetual desktop notification about an authorization request.

I don't see a way to respond to that request. When I dismiss the notification it just reappears a few seconds later, effectively obscuring that part of the screen forever.

How can I get rid of those notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling plugin AuthAgent stops the notifications from coming in.

This is for blueman 2.0.5 on Ubuntu 18.04 with i3 4.14.1.

Comment: Would this imply a security issue?

Comment: @Nico No idea. At the time, I couldn't _anwer_ the request and the device worked. So if the request _was_ supposed to serve a purpose, it failed at it. That said, it _might_ have been something like the "grant access to contacts" thing you get with cars -- never got anything when connecting the speaker to a phone, though -- in which case I wouldn't know whether disabling the plugin makes the demon fall back to "no" or "yes". In the latter case, I _guess_ there would be a security impact. In summary: I guess you should ask a new question about that? 

Answer (score 1):

I had luck with the following regarding my specific bluetooth audio adapter (connected to my HiFi. Bluetooth in, Chinch out, so to speak...), workingon a  Thinkpad with Ubuntu-MATE 21.04.

1. Figure out the ID
2. tell `bluetoothctl` to trust it. *(note: also reports sucess without sudo, but does not have the desired effect without sudo)*

```
    $> bluetoothctl info
        Device EB:06:12:34:56:78 (public)
            Name: Somebrand BT Adapter
            Alias: Somebrand BT Adapter
            Trusted: no
            ...

    $> sudo bluetoothctl trust EB:06:EF:76:77:D8
        Changing EB:06:12:34:56:78 trust succeeded
```

Comment: Interesting, will have to try this! I assume clicking "trust" in blueman-manager would do the some thing? I feel like @Nico's question from above applies as well: what does trusting a device _do_? 

Comment: @Raphael Also my guess, that "trust" on the dialog does exactly this command albeit without the `sudo` (and is happy because it seems 'successful') and there lies the problem, since it has no effect and more and more requests keep rolling in. I guess, trust will add this Bluetooth-IP (assuming it is something unique like a MAC-Address?) to [this sort of whitelist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/554053)?

Comment: This absolutely worked and also solved the problem of not being able to select the bluetooth device as an output (and therefore not being able to use it at all), which was the next problem I was going to try to solve! This should be the accepted answer IMO